# Representing an positive integer as a sum of three numbers

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

In how many ways the positive integer `n` can be represented as the sum of three different positive integers. The two methods are different if one contains a number that the other does not.

I've managed to get the following script to count the number of ways to write `n` as a sum of three numbers, but it's not takin the other condition in consiredation.

```py
def nways(n):  
  
    if (n <= 2):  
        return False
    else:           
        ways = (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2
          
    return ways
```

For example if n = 8 I would need to return 2 since 1 + 2 + 5 = 8 and 1 + 3 + 4 = 8, but the current function returns 21...

What would be the correct algorithm and math behind this?

Comment: Try working backwards; brute force a solution using 3 for loops, test it for the numbers 3 through 10, then work out the mathematical formula from those results

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
def nways(n):
    nways = 0
    for i in range(1, n-2):
        min_j, max_j = i+1, (n-i-1)//2
        nways += (max_j - min_j + 1) if max_j >= min_j else 0
    return nways
```

This algorithm consumes `O(N)` time and `O(1)` space.

### Explanation

Let's denote the three positive numbers as `i`, `j`, `k`.

And since they are all different, these three numbers must be greater than or smaller than each other. We assume the smallest number to be `i`, the middle one to be `j`, the largest to be `k`. So then the relation would be `i < j < k`.

Take `n = 18` for example

- we start from `i = 1`, then `j + k` should be `17`.

  - So `(j,k)` could be from `(2,12)`, `(3,14)`, ... to `(8,9)`.
  - Notice `(j,k)` couldn't be `(9,8)`, `(10,7)` because `j<k`
  - Therefore `min_j` would be `i+1` (in this case `2`), `max_j` would be `(n-i-1)//2` (in this case `8`)
  - Number of `(j, k)` combinations are `max_j - min_j + 1` which is `7` pairs in this case
- we go on with `i = 2`, then `j + k` should be `16`.

  - `min_j` would be `i+1` (in this case `3`), `max_j` would be `(n-i-1)//2` (in this case `7`)
  - Number of `(j, k)` combinations are `max_j - min_j + 1` which is `5` pairs in this case

We try all the possible values of `i` then add up all the combinations of `(j, k)` pair, then we get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use brute-force, with some more works:

- check if three terms is different
- store a set of unique terms
- the length of that set is your result

```py
def ways(n):
  tuple_sum_set = set()

  for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
      for k in range(1, n+1):
        if i + j + k == n and len(set([i, j, k])) == 3:
          tuple_sum_set.add(tuple(sorted([i,j,k])))

  print(tuple_sum_set)
  return len(tuple_sum_set)

print(ways(8))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/ChocolateHelplessLivecd

Answer (score 0):

A very different approach would be to use a constraint solver. Here is an example:

```
import constraint as con

n = 8

p = con.Problem()
p.addVariables(['x','y','z'],range(1,n-2))
p.addConstraint(con.ExactSumConstraint(n))
p.addConstraint(lambda a, b, c : a < b < c, ("x", "y", "z"))
sols = p.getSolutions()

print(len(sols))
sols
```

This gives:

```
2
[{'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 5}]
```

I am not aware of a simple formula that predicts the number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some pretty significant optimizations to @hgb123's already great answer to still use brute-force, but be a little more clever about it:

```
def ways(n):
  tuple_sum_set = set()

  for i in range(1, n-2):
    for j in range(i+1, n-2):
      for k in range(j+1, n-2):
        if i + j + k == n:
          tuple_sum_set.add((i,j,k))

  print(tuple_sum_set)
  return len(tuple_sum_set)
```

(If you up-vote this answer, please up-vote @hgb123's as well as this is a derivative of his answer)